# many to one association inserts instead of update

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

My Parent class

```
@Entity
public class Trailer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = “trailer_id", nullable = false)
    private Long trailerId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = “trailer”,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Item> items;
}
```

Child class

```
@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    @Column(name = “upc”, nullable = false)
    private Long upc;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "trailer_id", referencedColumnName = "trailer_id")
    private Trailer trailer;
}
```

A Trailer can have multiple unique Items, but the same trailer may bring different set of unique items later.

Service Class

```
 public void addOrderToDB() {

        List<Trailer> trailer = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        

        trailer = Trailer.builder().build();
        Item item1 = Item.builder().setTrailer(trailer).build();
        Item item2 = Item.builder().setTrailer(trailer).build();

        items.add(item1)
        items.add(item2)
       
        ItemRepository.saveAll(items);
}
```

Why am i trying to saving from many side:
because the unique key is upc here.

At the time i am inserting the Item,  it is inserting new entry for the Trailer corresponding to each Item entry of the same object.

Expected output:

```
Trailer table
trailer_id
1

Item table 
trailer_id  upc
  1         001
  1         002
```

Actual output:

```
Trailer table
trailer_id
1
2

Item table 
trailer_id  upc
  2         001
  2         002
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you do not synchronise the relationships properly: You make each `Item` aware of its `Trailer` but not the other way around. A nice way to do this is to have an add and a remove method in your parent object.

```
@Entity
public class Trailer {
    ...

    void addItem(Item item) {
        items.add(item);
        item.setTrailer(this);
    }

    void removeItem(Item item) {
        items.remove(item);
        item.setTrailer(null);
    }

    ...
}
```

You then add each new `Item` to the respective `Trailer` with the `addItem` method. It might then not be relevant from which side you save. Keys have to be unique anyway, just have a look how you generate the key for `Item`.

```
trailer.addItem(item1);
trailer.addItem(item2);
repository.save(trailer);
```

Comment: Hey Felix, even this did not solve my problem.

Comment: @YASHIGUPTA the answer given by Felix should work.
You can also debug and try to check why it is getting saved as separate entity.
You can enable hibernate logs to log the generatd SQL statements and check

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
public class Trailer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = “trailer_id", nullable = false)
    private Long trailerId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = “trailer”,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Remove redendent:

```
@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    @Column(name = “upc”, nullable = false)
    private Long upc;
}
```

then,

```
public void addOrderToDB() {

        List<Trailer> trailer = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        

        trailer = Trailer.builder().build();
        Item item1 = Item.builder().build();
        Item item2 = Item.builder().build();

        trailer.add(item1);
        trailer.add(item2);

        items.add(item1);
        items.add(item2);
       
        ItemRepository.saveAll(items);
}
```